# How can I pass the elements in a Perl array reference as separate arguments to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, reference, dereference

I have a list that contains arguments I want to pass to a function. How do I call that function?

For example, imagine I had this function:

```
sub foo {
  my ($arg0, $arg1, $arg2) = @_;
  print "$arg0 $arg1 $arg2\n";
}
```

And let's say I have:

```
my $args = [ "la", "di", "da" ];
```

How do I call `foo` without writing `foo($$args[0], $$args[1], $$args[2])`?

Comment: Where does the `APPLY` come from?  Is this a construct in another language?

Comment: APPLY comes from LISP http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/21.html

Comment: @daotoad Comes from Lisp but most languages have their equivalent form of it. It's one of those things that's really hard to Google for since various languages make up different terminology for the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foo(@$args)
```

That is not actually an `apply` function. That syntax just dereferences an array reference back to plain array. [man perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) tells you more about referecences.

Comment: You might also consider not constructing the reference to begin with, i.e. `@args = ("la", "de", "dah")` or even `@args = qw(la de dah);` and then passing it with `foo(@args)`. This is cleaner and more straightforward than doing the reference dance, though if you have other constraints (the array is already part of a data structure, for instance) it's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 11):

You dereference an array reference by sticking `@` in front of it.

```
foo( @$args );
```

Or if you want to be more explicit:

```
foo( @{ $args } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
foo(@$args);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foo(@$args);
```

Or, if you have a reference to `foo`:

```
my $func = \&foo;
...
$func->(@$args);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. foo(@{$args})